# change alpha level of javascript thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins

I'm using a plugin to display an image carousel. The thumbnails which are used to navigate are set the where any image not currently selected is "greyed out." How do I change the lessen the degree to which they are "greyed out?"

[Live site.](http://urbanpalate.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opacity is specified in the selector at line 228 of your `settings.css` file:

```
.tp-bullets.tp-thumbs .bullet {
    ...
    opacity: 0.5;
    ...
}
```

There are other vendor-specific properties in there (including an `-ms-filter` property for IE), so you'll have to change those to match.